# Minimal free resolution of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I wish to find a minimal free resolution of ideal $$I=(x_0^2-x_2x_3,x_0x_1-x_3^2,x_0x_2-x_1^2,x_1x_3-x_2^2,x_0x_3-x_1x_2)$$ in the polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$.

I tried to compute the syzygy of a map from a free module $\oplus Se_i \longrightarrow I$ where $e_i$ maps to each generator of $I$. Repeating such process, we may get a free resolution, but I have no idea whether it is minimal or not. How could one check the minimality of a given free resolution ? Maybe an easier computation need to change the basis.

Comment: Show us the resolution you got and then let's see if it is minimal or not. (Honestly, I have serious doubts that one can find a resolution of  $I$ by hand.)

Comment: @user26857 I think you are right. I am not able to compute this either just by computing syzygies. But this is an exercise from Eisenbud in the chapter about Grobner basis. He claims the free resolution is symmetric and should be of rank 1, 5, 5, 1. I tried the method similar to his proof of Hilbert's syzygy theorem, but it may not work.

Comment: Did you try using Macaulay2?

Comment: @Pedro Not yet. Regarding this is an exercise, I think it can be solved manually. And the hint already says that the resolution is symmetric with ranks of free modules 1,5,5,1, and the first and last matrices should be transposes of one another up to change of basis with middle matrix being skew-symmetric. Unfortunately, I still have no ideal how to construct such resolutions.